# Migrate Solution from OSX XS2 to Win7 VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have produce my code on XS2 on OSX. Now i'd like to run it on Visual Studio using remote debugger. But when i open Visual Studio 2012 it crashs on startup. Maybe it can't load iOS Solution?

Some experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to Monotouch plug-in installed in VisualStudio to ensure compatibility with MonoTouch before the release of Xamarin Studio plugin.

Deleting that plugin I solved my problem.